# Possible ways to identify Linux friendly code

Tags: c++, porting

I have a program that accesses a device through the serial port and reads the flash memory and displays it in command prompt. It saves the readings to ms access for logging.

I want to use this program on Linux so I figured that if I remove the MS access logging code it would port as serial ports and command prompt should be that same in linux.

What I am looking for is a way to identify any code that will not run on linux. Best case scenario would be a program that takes my source file and highlights the offending lines of code.

failing that what are the best ways of identifying code that needs to be changed to make the program run on linux?

EDIT: I have to use the borland 5.5 compiler and have very limited access to linux machines for testing so need to build the program in a windows environment if that is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try compiling the code on Linux and try to look in to the compile errors, Whatever doesn't belong to Linux won't compile and you need to port/write similar functionality for Linux port.

Or am I missing something here? This looks fairly straightforward.

Comment: Well, maybe there could be semantic differences. Those are not detectable at compile-time.

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes: Indeed, Clean compilation does not warranty desirable execution/Output.

Comment: @Als due to its age the program will only compile in borland 5.5, something to do with ancient dependencies and incompatibility with new techniques. As far as I can tell  borland 5.5 wont run on linux. can you offer any other solutions ?

Comment: @Skeith: It's a miracle a compiler *that* old works at all. As long as you can't compile on a Linux compiler, there's no way you can even compile for Linux.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you can only compile with Borland 5.5, it's physically impossible for you to port to Linux. How can you compile for Linux without using a compiler that can target Linux?

You need to install Linux on a dev box, get G++, and use that compiler. There's no other way to do it.